# How to combine return type polymorphism with parametric polymorphism in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, parametric-polymorphism

I have set of wrapper types `FilePath`s (due to restrictions of library I'm using, that create a specific storage based on provided type) and couple of records that I need to obtain from these file-paths.

```hs
newtype SourceFilepath = SourceFilepath String deriving (Show)
newtype HeaderFilepath = HeaderFilepath String deriving (Show)
-- ..many more wrappers

data Source =
  Source {..}

data Header = 
  Header {..}

data Metadata = 
  Metadata {..}

-- .. many more record types
```

I want to create generalized function `loadSource` that accepts some types (actually only filepath wrappers) and based on the provided type produces value of another specific type (`Source`, `Header`, `Metadata`, etc.). Pseudocode:

```hs
loadSource :: a -> Compiler b
loadSource (SourceFilepath path) = subload path
loadSource (HeaderFilepath path) = subload path
-- .. other cases for other types 
--
-- `a` can be filepath wrappers
-- different `a` can lead to the same `b` sometimes
```

this function isn't operational I get multiple `a’ is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature` and `rigid b..` errors.

so I don't have multiple functions like this (code working properly):

```hs
subload :: FromJSON b => FilePath -> Compiler b
subload path = <already implemented operational logic>

loadHeader :: HeaderFilepath -> Comiler Header
loadHeader (HeaderPath path) = subload path

loadMetadata :: MetadataFilepath -> Comiler Metadata
loadMetadata (MetadataFilepath path) = subload path

-- .. many more similar functions
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this, though as @DanielWagner says, it's hard to tell what will work best for you without additional detail on what you're trying to achieve.

The simplest is probably to use a type class with an associated type family (or a multiparameter type class with a functional dependency) to map the type of the file path wrapper to the compiler subtype.  The type family approach looks like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class Loadable a where
  filepath :: a -> String
  type Load a
```

with boilerplatey instances like:

```
instance Loadable SourceFilepath where
  filepath (SourceFilepath pth) = pth
  type Load SourceFilepath = Source
instance Loadable HeaderFilepath where
  filepath (HeaderFilepath pth) = pth
  type Load HeaderFilepath = Header
instance Loadable MetadataFilepath where
  filepath (MetadataFilepath pth) = pth
  type Load MetadataFilepath = Metadata
```

Note that there's no problem here mapping two file path wrappers to the same compiler subtype (e.g., `type Load HeaderFilepath = Source` would work fine).

Given:

```
subload :: FromJSON b => FilePath -> Compiler b
subload = ...
```

the definition of `loadSource` is:

```
loadSource :: (Loadable a, FromJSON (Load a)) => a -> Compiler (Load a)
loadSource = subload . filepath
```

after which:

```
> :t loadSource (SourceFilepath "bob")
loadSource (SourceFilepath "bob") :: Compiler Source
> :t loadSource (MetadataFilepath "alice")
loadSource (MetadataFilepath "alice") :: Compiler Metadata
```

You can substantially reduce boilerplate by parametrizing the wrapper, and -- like @DanielWagner -- I don't understand your comment about the compiler treating them as the same type of file, so you'd need to show us what's going wrong when you try that.

Anyway, my complete source for the original type family solution:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

import Data.Aeson
import GHC.Generics

newtype SourceFilepath = SourceFilepath String deriving (Show)
newtype HeaderFilepath = HeaderFilepath String deriving (Show)
newtype MetadataFilepath = MetadataFilepath String deriving (Show)

data Source = Source deriving (Generic)
data Header = Header deriving (Generic)
data Metadata = Metadata deriving (Generic)

instance FromJSON Source
instance FromJSON Header
instance FromJSON Metadata

data Compiler b = Compiler

subload :: FromJSON b => FilePath -> Compiler b
subload = undefined

class Loadable a where
  filepath :: a -> String
  type Load a
instance Loadable SourceFilepath where
  filepath (SourceFilepath pth) = pth
  type Load SourceFilepath = Source
instance Loadable HeaderFilepath where
  filepath (HeaderFilepath pth) = pth
  type Load HeaderFilepath = Header
instance Loadable MetadataFilepath where
  filepath (MetadataFilepath pth) = pth
  type Load MetadataFilepath = Metadata

loadSource :: (Loadable a, FromJSON (Load a)) => a -> Compiler (Load a)
loadSource = subload . filepath
```

and the complete source for a tagged solution:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

import Data.Aeson
import GHC.Generics

newtype TypedFilePath a = TypedFilePath FilePath deriving (Show)

data Source = Source deriving (Generic)
data Header = Header deriving (Generic)
data Metadata = Metadata deriving (Generic)

instance FromJSON Source
instance FromJSON Header
instance FromJSON Metadata

data Compiler b = Compiler

subload :: FromJSON b => FilePath -> Compiler b
subload = undefined

type family Load a where
  Load Source = Source
  Load Header = Header
  Load Metadata = Metadata

loadSource :: FromJSON (Load a) => TypedFilePath a -> Compiler (Load a)
loadSource (TypedFilePath fn) = subload fn
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped, type class with an associated type family covered my cases.

Answer (score 1):

Just make your wrapper parameterized, too:

```
newtype WrappedFilePath a = WrappedFilePath FilePath

loadSource :: FromJSON a => WrappedFilePath a -> Compiler a
loadSource (WrappedFilePath p) = subload fp
```

You can reuse [`Tagged`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged-0.8.6/docs/Data-Tagged.html) instead of creating the new `WrappedFilePath` if you like.

Comment: I tried that and compiler subsystem thinks that it's same type of files and tries to apply functions that won't work. That's why I need to have separate `HeaderFilePath` and `SourceFilePath`.

Comment: @FilipvanHoft I don't understand your first comment. Your pseudocode already calls the same `subload` function for both patterns in `loadSource`; does this not reflect what you actually want to happen? If not, then perhaps you can give some details of what you *do* want to happen?

Comment: `loadSource` isn't operational that's how I imagine I might use it.

Comment: @FilipvanHoft Okay. I don't think anybody can help you further until you say more about what behavior you want.